# how to send a model id while using javascript in django

Tags: python, django, web

I'm trying to delete a model instance when clicked on a button but before that i want to show a confirm box using JS, if the confirm box results true then i want to head over to the view to delete the instance also passing the instance id.
Here Django is showing an Error
NoReverseMatch at /profile/myprojects
Reverse for 'project_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found.

This is my button

```
<button onclick="delFunction()" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete  
Project</button>
```

This is the JS code

```
 function delFunction() {
  var txt;
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the project?")) {
    window.location.href = "{% url 'project_delete' project.id %}";
  } 
}
```

Comment: I think your function should accept an `id` param and then you can use that into the url?

Comment: Do you have an object call `project` in your template context?

Comment: yes, I have a Project object

Comment: I tried passing the id as a parameter but it didn't work!